# Python typing: partial specialization of a generic type

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy, typing

I have have a generic class hierarchy, mirroring the hierarchy of the type parameter.  I am trying to add proper type annotations to these classes.

In the example below I'm attempting to partially specialize the `Root` class:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")

class Root(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, value: _T):
        self.value = value

_Number = TypeVar("_Number", int, float)

class FooNumber(Root[_Number]):
    def __init__(self, value: _Number):
        super().__init__(value)
```

... mypy reports on the `__init__` upcall from `FooNumber.__init__()`:

```
test-mypy-typevar-inherit.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Root" has incompatible type "int"; expected "_Number"  [arg-type]
test-mypy-typevar-inherit.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Root" has incompatible type "float"; expected "_Number"  [arg-type]
```

The goal is to then declare `FooInt` deriving from `FooNumer[int]` (and similarly for `FooFloat`).
A direct specialization of `FooInt` from `Root[int]` shows (as expected) no issue, and I don't feel it's very clear why this `FooNumber` definition causes any problem.

What would be the proper way to declare it ?

Comment: It's definitely a bug, please check `mypy` issue tracker for presence of this and report if it isn't there. `mypy` analyzes the call as if there are several narrowed calls for some reasons.